# Testing usage of Firebase create user functions with Coroutines and calling await() leads to "This job has not completed yet"

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, junit4, kotlin-coroutines

I have a simplified test case where I'm calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(...).await()` from `FirebaseAuth` that leads to the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet
```

I'm using the `InstantTaskExecutorRule` but this doesn't help.

Here is my simplified test class:

```
import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runBlockingTest
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test

class FirebaseCoroutineTest {
    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    val auth = Firebase.auth.apply {
        this.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 9099)
    }


    @Test
    fun testCreateUser() = runBlockingTest {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("test@user.null", "testpwd").await()

    }
}
```

What's the correct way to do this test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `runBlocking` instead of `runBlockingTest` solves the issue.